# How validate a logical expression using Regular expression Or C#

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I need to validate the Logical Expressions like,

```
( ( var1 == var2 ) && ( var2 >= var4 || var1 > var5 ) )

( var1 < var2 ) 

( var1 == var2 || var3 != var4 )
```

Each braces, variables and logical operator are separated by single SPACE.

I need a regular expression to parse it.

Or tell me some logic to validate this with C#.

Thanks.

Comment: Because of the nested brackets it is not a job for regular expressions. I would suggest you remove the "using Regular expression" from your headline, then more c# people will look at your question.

Comment: Does it have to be using Regular Expressions? Could you use a 3rd party tool like ANTLR?

Answer (score 0):

Either build your own parser, or see below (found [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=397264)). You'll need to change it a bit to account for variables, but that shouldn't be too hard. Either, parse them before passing them to the function, or change the function to except variable names and values.

```
    using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
    using Microsoft.CSharp;
    using System.Reflection;
    /// <summary>
    /// A simple function to get the result of a C# expression (basic and advanced math possible)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command">String value containing an expression that can evaluate to a double.</param>
    /// <returns>a Double value after evaluating the command string.</returns>
    private double ProcessCommand(string command)
    {
        //Create a C# Code Provider
        CSharpCodeProvider myCodeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        // Build the parameters for source compilation.
        CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
        cp.GenerateExecutable = false;//No need to make an EXE file here.
        cp.GenerateInMemory = true;   //But we do need one in memory.
        cp.OutputAssembly = "TempModule"; //This is not necessary, however, if used repeatedly, causes the CLR to not need to 
                                          //load a new assembly each time the function is run.
        //The below string is basically the shell of a C# program, that does nothing, but contains an
        //Evaluate() method for our purposes.  I realize this leaves the app open to injection attacks, 
        //But this is a simple demonstration.
        string TempModuleSource = "namespace ns{" +
                                  "using System;" +
                                  "class class1{" +
                                  "public static double Evaluate(){return " + command + ";}}} ";  //Our actual Expression evaluator

        CompilerResults cr = myCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp,TempModuleSource);
        if (cr.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            //If a compiler error is generated, we will throw an exception because 
            //the syntax was wrong - again, this is left up to the implementer to verify syntax before
            //calling the function.  The calling code could trap this in a try loop, and notify a user 
            //the command was not understood, for example.
            throw new ArgumentException("Expression cannot be evaluated, please use a valid C# expression");
        }
        else
        {
            MethodInfo Methinfo = cr.CompiledAssembly.GetType("ns.class1").GetMethod("Evaluate");
            return (double)Methinfo.Invoke(null, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Did you test it?

Comment: No, and from looking at the original thread, needs at least one edit, will test and update.

Comment: Thanks George, But just i need to validate the given expression like whether an expression is in correct format or not. I don't want to to evaluate the expression. that's why i asked in Regular Expression.

Comment: You could use the above method to evaluate it. If it fails then it's not a valid expression.

Comment: I am having only a string which is a logical expression. i cant assign values to the variables. So before going to evaluate i need validate it.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this and I wanted to do it as a regex, I would create a multipass algorithm with each pass eliminating a validated subcase (e.g. replace a validated "( x == y )" with "x"

Perhaps something starting with: `s/\b\w+ $op \w+\b/^^MAGICTOKEN^^/g`

Then any /$op/ would be illegal.

Then focus in a loop on each paren:  `s/\(( [^\)]+ )\)/^^MAGICTOKEN^^/`

While focused on $1, reduce:  `s/ $MAGICTOKRE $BOOL $MAGICTOKRE / ^^MAGICTOKEN^^ /`
Run the reduce in a loop until it stops reducing.
If `$1 ne " ^^MAGICTOKEN^^ "`, error

After the focus loop, most likely `$expression ne "^^MAGICTOKEN^^"` would indicate an error.

Comment: I suggest you replacing your code to C# so the OP can understand it ;)